# Syntax Error In Array

Tags: php, arrays, magento, syntax

1- If i write this line like that; the API i use(magento 2 rest api) is not accepting **category_ids** value:

```
$cat = '["34","22","14"]';
array( 'attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => $cat),
```

2- If i write the line like this; the API is not saving **category_ids** again:

```
array( 'attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => '["34","22","14"]'),
```

3- But if i write like this; everything is ok:

```
array( 'attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => ["34","22","14"]),
```

i have to write **category_ids** value as a variable; so, could someone help me to write correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put your array inside `single quotes`.

```
// Change this
$cat = '["34","22","14"]';

// to this
$cat = ["34","22","14"];
```